# how can I set a timer overflow for ATmega328p in assembly?

Tags: assembly, avr, atmel

I've been trying to create a program in assembly that rotate a single bit either to left or right, every time a Timer Overflow interrupt occurs. Here is my code, but for some reason it doesn't works. I'm new in this world of programming assembly and I wish that someone could help me here, because I'm stuck. Here is my code:

```
/*
 * lab3b.asm
 *
 *  Created: 10/18/2014 8:03:22 PM
 *   Author: Isaac Vilchez
 */ 

.include "m328pdef.inc"
.org 0x0000 jmp main
.org 0x0020 jmp TIM0_OVF_ISR

main:
    .org 0x0033

//Config de Stack Pointer y Timer0
    ldi R16, high(RAMEND)
    out SPH, R16
    ldi R16, low(RAMEND)
    out SPL, R16
    sei

//Inicializando los puertos D y B como salida
ldi r16, 0x00
out DDRC, r16
ldi r16, 0xFF
out DDRD, r16
out DDRB, r16

//Configurando timer0 al intervalo maximo de duracion al timer0
    ldi R19, 0x00
    out TCNT0, R19 //Para que el conteo empiece en 0
    ldi R20, 0x05
    out TCCR0B, R20
    ldi R23, 0x01
    sts TIMSK0, R23 //habitlita el timer0

//Registros proposito general
ldi r16, 0x01   ;registro puerto D
ldi r22, 0x10   ;mascara para ejecutar rot_izqPB
ldi r23, 0x80   ;mascara PD
ldi r20, 0x01   ;registro puerto B
ldi r21, 0x00   ;mascara de 0

out PORTB, r21  ;Posicion inicial puerto B
out PORTD, r21  ;Posicion inicial puerto D

//Cargando a R16 con 0x01 para comenzar la rotacion hacia la izquierda
TIM0_OVF_ISR:
    in r24, PINC    ;Se guarda el valor del puerto C en R24
    andi r24, 0x01  ;Se enmascara el puerto C
    cpi r24, 0x01   ;Se compara con 0x01 para ver su estado
    breq rot_derPB  ;Si esta encendido, rota a la derecha
    rjmp rot_izqPD  ;Si esta apagado rota a la izquierda


//Rotacion hacia la izquierda
rot_izqPD:
    ldi r16, 0x01
    rjmp rot_izqPD1

rot_izqPD1:
    out PORTD, r16
    cpi r16, 0x00
    breq rot_izqPB
    ROL r16
    rjmp wait

//Rotacion hacia la izquierda
rot_izqPB:
    ldi r20, 0x01
    rjmp rot_izqPB1

rot_izqPB1:
    out PORTB, r20
    LSL r20
    cp r20, r22
    breq rot_izqPB1
    rjmp wait

//Rotacion hacia la derecha
rot_derPB:
    ldi r16, 0x08
    rjmp rot_derPB1

rot_derPB1:
    out PORTB, r16
    LSR r16
    cpi r16, 0x00
    breq rot_derPD
    rjmp wait

//Rotacion hacia la derecha
rot_derPD:
    ldi r16, 0x80

rot_derPD1:
    out PORTB, r21
    out PORTD, r16
    LSR r16
    cp r16, r21
    ;breq wait
    rjmp wait

wait:
    brvs TIM0_OVF_ISR
    rjmp wait
```

EDIT:
 Here is my new code. This one is working:

```
/*
 * lab3b.asm
 *
 *  Created: 10/18/2014 8:03:22 PM
 *   Author: Isaac Vilchez
 */ 

.include "m328pdef.inc"
.org 0x0000 jmp begin
.org 0x0020 jmp TIM0_OVF_ISR

begin:
    .org 0x0033

//Config de Stack Pointer y Timer0
ldi R16, high(RAMEND)
out SPH, R16
ldi R16, low(RAMEND)
out SPL, R16

//Inicializando los puertos D y B como salida
ldi r16,    0x00
out DDRC,   r16
ldi r16,    0xFF
out DDRD,   r16
out DDRB,   r16

//Configurando timer0 al intervalo maximo de duracion al timer0
ldi R19,    0x00
out TCNT0,  R19 //Para que el conteo empiece en 0
ldi R20,    0x05
out TCCR0B, R20
ldi R23,    0x01
sts TIMSK0, R23 //habitlita el timer0

//Habilitando las interrupciones globales
SEI

//Configuracion de Registros
main:
    ldi r16, 0x01
    ldi r17, 0x00
    ldi r19, 0x80
    mov r20, r16
    ldi r21, 0
    mov r23, r19
    ldi r25, 0x01

//Loop de espera en lo que se realiza la interrupcion
wait:
    rjmp wait

//Enciende el led de PB4 y espera a la interrupcion
onPB:
    ldi r22, 0x80
    out PORTB, r22
    rjmp wait

//Enciende el led de PB4 y espera a la interrupcion
ledpb4:
    ldi r22, 0x80
    out PORTB, r22
    reti

reset:
    ldi r16,    0x01
    ldi r18,    0x08
    ldi r19,    0x80
    mov r20,    r16
    ldi r21,    0
    mov r23,    r19
    reti

//Rotacion hacia la izquierda
rot_izqPD:
    out PORTB,  r21
    out PORTD,  r16
    ldi r17, 0x00
    LSL r16
    cp  r16,    r17
    breq    rot_izqPB
    reti

//Rotacion hacia la izquierda
rot_izqPB:
    out PORTB,  r20
    LSL r20
    ldi r17, 0x10
    cp r20, r17
    breq    reset
    reti

//Rotacion hacia la derecha
rot_derPB:
    out PORTB,  r18
    ldi r17, 0x00
    cp r18, r17
    breq rot_derPD
    LSR r18
    reti

//Rotacion hacia la derecha
rot_derPD:
    out PORTB,  r21
    out PORTD,  r19
    cp  r19,    r21
    breq reset
    LSR r19
    reti

TIM0_OVF_ISR:
    in  r24,    PINC    ;Se guarda el valor del puerto C en R24
    andi r24,   0x01    ;Se enmascara el puerto C
    cp  r24,    r25     ;Se compara con 0x01 para ver su estado
    breq    rot_derPB   ;Si esta encendido, rota a la derecha
    rcall   rot_izqPD   ;Si esta apagado rota a la izquierda
    reti
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use an interrupt routine, and also poll an interrupt flag. You should only be doing one of these. I suggest the interrupt routine.

(Also, you are trying to poll the wrong flag. `brvs` tests the flag for an overflow in an arithmetic operation. The timer overflow flag is something else.)

You have the jump to the routine in the correct place in the interrupt table `.org 0x0020 jmp TIM0_OVF_ISR`. And you enable interrupts in main. This looks okay to me at first glance.

When an interrupt occurs, the address of the next instruction (PC) is pushed on the stack, the interrupt flag is cleared, interrupts are disabled, and the flow of control jumps to the address in the table.

But you never return from the interrupt. At the end of the routine, you should be calling `reti`. This will cause the flow to return to where it was when it was interrupted by popping the address off the stack, and enable interrupts again. You should not be entering a busy loop in the interrupt routine, as at the bottom of this program.

The structure of the program should be more like

```
.include "m328pdef.inc"
.org 0x0000 jmp main
.org 0x0020 jmp TIM0_OVF_ISR

main: 
    Configure all the ports and timer and interrupts.
    sei
wait:
    rjmp wait

TIM0_OVF_ISR: 
    Do the routine
    reti
```

Also note that you do not need some of the rjmp instructions currently in your code.

```
rot_izqPD:
    ldi r16, 0x01
    rjmp rot_izqPD1   ;;; not needed. This is the next instruction anyway.

rot_izqPD1:
    out PORTD, r16
```

EDIT: with subroutines

If you want to you subroutines for the rotations, you can `call` them as long as they end with `ret`. Using `rjmp` everywhere is really bad, and it is getting you into trouble.

```
.include "m328pdef.inc"
.org 0x0000 jmp main
.org 0x0020 jmp TIM0_OVF_ISR

main: 
    Configure and initialize all the ports and timer and interrupts.
    call rot_derPB   ;; called the subroutine from main. flow returns here.
    sei
wait:
    rjmp wait

rot_derPB:
    do the rotation
    ret

TIM0_OVF_ISR: 
    Do the routine. e.g.,
    call rot_derPB   ;; called the subroutine in the handler. flow returns here.
    reti
```

EDIT 2: if/else branching

A common trick for if/else branching is to skip forward for the "if" clause, and run the "else" clause first. For example, instead of

```
/Cargando a R16 con 0x01 para comenzar la rotacion hacia la izquierda
TIM0_OVF_ISR:
    in r24, PINC    ;Se guarda el valor del puerto C en R24
    andi r24, 0x01  ;Se enmascara el puerto C
    cpi r24, 0x01   ;Se compara con 0x01 para ver su estado
    breq rot_derPB  ;Si esta encendido, rota a la derecha
    rjmp rot_izqPD  ;Si esta apagado rota a la izquierda
```

reverse the order and write them as `call`s. Make sure to end the functions with `ret`.

```
/Cargando a R16 con 0x01 para comenzar la rotacion hacia la izquierda
TIM0_OVF_ISR:
    in r24, PINC    ;Se guarda el valor del puerto C en R24
    andi r24, 0x01  ;Se enmascara el puerto C
    cpi r24, 0x01   ;Se compara con 0x01 para ver su estado
    breq go_derPB
    call rot_izqPD  ;Si esta apagado rota a la izquierda
    bra TIMO_end
go_derPB:   
    call rot_derPB  ;Si esta encendido, rota a la derecha
TIM0_end:
    reti
```

Notice the branches are to places within the same function. To leave the function, you either call another function or return from the function. What you don't want is "spaghetti code" branching great distances through the program.

Comment: Hey UncleO! Please, look at the new answer I just posted. I fixed a bit the code as you told me to, but still haven't managed to work it. Please check it

Comment: Hi Isaac, you should edit your question rather than post an answer. But the new code still doesn't look right. Perhaps you should consider using the `call` and `ret` instructions, rather than `rjmp`. it still looks like you are entering a busy loop with interrupts disabled.

Comment: I think that it just stays at the "wait" loop and whenever I ask it to return from the interrupt, it just gets back to the loop.

Comment: I edited the answer to add subroutines. It looks like you want to rotate in main once, and then in the interrupt handler from then onwards.

Comment: I erased the "wait" loop. I can see clearly that the interrupt is actually working. how can I make that the rotation occurs just when there is an overflow of the timer?

Comment: Ok! let me try and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hey UncleO! I've been trying to fix the code and I structure it as you told me, but there must be still something I'm missing. I edited my question with the last code I tried. Can you give it a look?

Comment: You are still using branching instead of calls in some places. I will add more to my answer.